# JSONObject toString and Base64 performance

Tags: java, android, json

In my app I am sending base64 encoded files in Json format. My code is:

```
JSONObject jsonRequest = prepareJsonObject(expense, contentUri);
String jsonString = jsonRequest.toString();
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonString);
```

The jsonRequest object looks like this:

```
{
   "category":"660",
   "user":"458",
   "dated_on":"Wed Mar 12 10:38:11 GMT+00:00 2014",
   "description":"document",
   "gross_value":"-2.0",
   "currency":"GBP",
   "attachment":{
        "data":"<base64>"
        "mimetype":"image/jpeg"
   }
}
```

The problem is that `jsonRequest.toString()` is taking like 2 minutes for a 700Kb file.

Is there a way to make this quicker? Am I doing something wrong?

thanks.

EDIT: I am testing in an actual Nexus 4 running KITKAT.

For completion purpose, this is the code for prepareJsonObject(), which runs in less than 2 secs.

```
public static JSONObject prepareJsonObject(Expense expense, String contentUri){
        JSONObject expenseJson = null;
        try{
            expenseJson = new JSONObject();
            if(expense.getUserId()!=null) expenseJson.put("user", expense.getUserId().toString());
            if(expense.getProjectId()!=null) expenseJson.put("project", expense.getProjectId().toString());
            if(expense.getCurrency()!=null) expenseJson.put("currency", expense.getCurrency().toString());
            if(expense.getGrossValue()!=null) expenseJson.put("gross_value", expense.getGrossValue().toString());
            if(expense.getNativeGrossValue()!=null) expenseJson.put("native_gross_value", expense.getNativeGrossValue().toString());
            if(expense.getSalesTaxRate()!=null) expenseJson.put("sales_tax_rate", expense.getSalesTaxRate().toString());
            if(expense.getDescription()!=null)expenseJson.put("description", expense.getDescription().toString());
            if(expense.getDated()!=null)expenseJson.put("dated_on", expense.getDated());
            if(expense.getCategoryId()!=null) expenseJson.put("category", expense.getCategoryId().toString());
            if(expense.getManualSalesTaxAmount()!=null)expenseJson.put("manual_sales_tax_amount", expense.getManualSalesTaxAmount().toString());
            if(contentUri!=null){
                    JSONObject attachmentJson = new JSONObject();
                    String base64data = AttachmentsUtils.getBase64ForUri(Uri.parse(contentUri));
                    attachmentJson.put("data", base64data);
                    attachmentJson.put("content_type", AttachmentsUtils.getMimetypeFromContentUri(Uri.parse(contentUri)));
                    expenseJson.put("attachment", attachmentJson);

            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("ExpensesUtils", "Couldn't encode attachment: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return expenseJson;
    }
```

Comment: there's a missing semicolon after toString()

Comment: Has this time measured on an emulator or your actual device?

Comment: Measured in an actual Nexus 4 with KITKAT

Comment: I think prepareJsonObject() method take that much time, so add that cde too

Comment: OMAK means `prepareJsonObject();`, I think

Comment: have you tried to use a json streaming API instead of storing your full serialized object in a String ?

Comment: Please, @PierreRust, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: 700kb is quite large and a streaming API (like http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Streaming_API_Example) that writes content incrementally could hep. Not sure about it though ( that's why I did not post an answer yet) as your only big part is the base64 data.

Comment: @PierreRust, yes, the problem is the base64 data, if I remove it, works fine. I am going to give Jackson a try and see what happen.

Comment: Finally, i don't think you need streaming, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the `toString` pare the full content of your base64 data to handle unicode characters and escape some specific characters. You can see this in [JSONStringer#string](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/f2f7880a40aed1c8d9c27db49226e47396556aac/libcore/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONStringer.java), which is called for every string value in your [JsonObject](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/f2f7880a40aed1c8d9c27db49226e47396556aac/libcore/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONObject.java) when you call `toString`.

Of course, as your data is base64, you don't actually need this. So I think you will need to implement your own toString implementation, probably based on the `JSONStringer` without escaping

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the problem is there. I will give it a try.

Comment: Finally, what I am doing is create the JSONObject with everything but the base64 data. Then, getting the string from the JSONObject and inserting the base64 data on it. It is a pretty ugly solution, but now it takes less than a second for files that were taking more than 1 minute. Definitely, I will use Jackson on GSon next time.

Comment: Well, ugly but efficient and not that bad as long as you control the text you're inserting like this. If Jackson and Gson enforce the spec. (as they should) for text encoding, I suspect they would not perform any better for this particular issue.

Comment: I can't imagine I am the first who needs a JSON object containing base64 data. There must be a better solution for this case...